# Swagger Annotations for Customizing Responses?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Have a custom response setup like this:

```
public class CustomResponse {
    private int id;
    private String productName;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    // Constructor & along with Getters & Setters

}
```

My Swagger inside my ProductController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ProductController {

    @ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", 
                  value = "Retrieves reesults based on specific values set in the request parameters.", 
                  notes = "Sends back query results in JSON format after being processed.", 
                  produces = "application/json")
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
                        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful GET command", response = CustomResponse.class),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Entity Not Found"), 
                        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") 
                        })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json" )
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getQueryResults(@ApiParam(value = "productName", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "productName") String productName) throws IOException {
        // Implementation details
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I launch my webservice and open up Swagger's UI, I see a Model and Example Value for the CustomResponse...

Question(s):

1. How can I describe / document the individual attributes of the CustomRepsonse inside the Swagger? Meaning, is there a Swagger annotation to describe each field of the CustomResponse?
2. In the Example Value, is there a way I can also document the attributes with actual hardcoded data?

Right now, its showing up like this in Example Value:

```
{ "id" : 0, "productName" : "string","quantity" : 0, "price" : 0.00 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I describe / document the individual attributes of the CustomRepsonse inside the Swagger? Meaning, is there a Swagger annotation to describe each field of the CustomResponse?

Please pay your attention on annotation `@io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty` - it should help you to add doc for `customResponse`

```
public class CustomResponse {
    private int id;
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty(value = "my super product name")
    private String productName;
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "1,5,10,25,50")
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    // Constructor & along with Getters & Setters

}
```

> In the Example Value, is there a way I can also document the attributes with actual hardcoded data?

Definitely you can specify default values for `ApiParam`. I do not think there is a way to specify default data via swagger annotation for `CustomResponse` fields. Partly you can cover your needs using annotation `@io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty`.

- [overriding-property-datatypes](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#overriding-property-datatypes)
- [allowableValues](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#allowableValues())
- [other properties of the ApiModelProperty - java doc](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html)

---

Using swagger you can define web doc for `CustomResponse` but default values will be specified by default in the class level (constructor or field declaration). To make it more flexible I prefer use [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) where I configure exception handlers and here I have chance map `code` on correspond exception and specify values for my custom responses (default values too).

---

As I can see in your swagger doc you have overridden `code` - default `message` mapping. To make it working it would be useful [to change some configuration](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#quick-start-guides) (pay your attention on `.useDefaultResponseMessages(false)` and followed rows responsible for this).

Comment: Thanks Sergii - Allowable values only seem to be values that are allowable but not where I can specify default values for the response type under Example Value? The ApiModelProperty helped out a lot.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover y, you can't specify default values for model with `ApiModelProperty`. May be later they provide this ability, will see.

Comment: Can you provide default values for a response at all?

Comment: I use`@ControllerAdvice` to provide correct response builder with clean code. Each exception contains information about validated fields or unsupported operations. Some times I have not enough data to provide into my customRuntimeExceptions. In this case I use general exception information to provide default data for `CustomResponse`. I hope it helps.

Comment: can you provide an example of your ControllerAdvice? "...  you have overridden code - default message mapping." Where did I do this?

Comment: I think controller advice should be different question. I can't add here `ControllerAdvice` example in comments because of restricted space. I can't add example into different answer or in same because of general question was about different part. Ask one more question, put link in comments, I'll add answer and example. Is it ok for you?